# Redirect from an IP address to a domain

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

How can I redirect a page from an IP address to domain name *my.page.com*? Everything works when I open the page via *my.page.com*. When I open via the IP address I get "incorrect certificate "CN = Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate
O = Acme Co".

I want only to redirect people from an IP address to a domain.

`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
name: web-ingress
annotations:
kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
tls:

- hosts:

  - my.page.com
    secretName: tls-secret
    rules:
- host: my.page.com
  http:
  paths:

  - path: /api
    backend:
    serviceName: api
    servicePort: 8090
  - path: /
    backend:
    serviceName: app
    servicePort: 8080`

I installed Ingress from [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Comment: There is a piece of [documentation with examples](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#examples) on topic. Will try checking if you can achive IP rewrite

Answer (score 0):

There is good documentation with examples on topic.

Generally there are two ways to proceed:

- modifying the Nginx configuration and [adding rewrite rules](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/) there. For that, you need to pass new parts of the configuration through the [snippets](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/).
- use an ingress controller like [Træfik](https://traefik.io/). Træfik allows you to match specific patter in URL and [rewrite](https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/redirectregex/) it on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a deployment that gives a 404 or nginx 404.html page which do redirect to the main domain.

Then In Ingress deployment pass that service as the default service `--default-backend-service=<namespace>/<service>`

Which mean, when none of the rules match with the ingress file, then the default service will take that request.

In your case, the IP address would be showing an nginx page that 'page not found', if the default service was not set.

Read here: *[Default backend](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/default-backend/)*